# diagonalization , help me to to find out which one

Tags: diagonalization

[image]

Could anyone only help me to find out which one is diagonalizable?

Comment: Do you know the criteria for a $n\times n$ matrix to be diagonalizable?

Comment: yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssss, if its minimal polynomial factors into linear factors

Comment: Please don’t include the bulk of your question as an image. It’s neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers. If you take your own time to do this, then more people might be include to take up their own time answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It's not hard to see that
\begin{align}
v_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1 \\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},  \ \
v_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1 \\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
are eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues, $3$ and $1$ respectively. Consider $B-3I$ and $B-I$ and see what you get.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "it's not hard to *check*" instead of "to see", because I can't see easily at all how **to get** those eigenvalues without explicitly calculating the characteristic polynomial...

Comment: @DonAntonio Because of the zero block at the lower left corner of the matrices we could isolate the upper left corner matrix. It's not hard to see $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvectors $[1, 1]^T$ and $[1, -1]^T$, with corresponding eigenvalues $3, 1$. This is how I constructed the eigenvectors for the original matrix.