# Finding eigenvalues for a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvalues for this $4\times4$ matrix $A$, where $A$ is

\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
          0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

I was wondering if there is an easy way to do it or do I have to find the determinant the long way?

Comment: I think that you definitely have to compute the determinant.

Comment: My professor gave me a hint.  He said he rigged this matrix so that there is an easy way to find the characteristic polynomial.  I cannot think of a way...

Comment: Well, this is a block matrix, so the characteristic polynomial is $$((2-x)^2-1)^2$$ Compute the $2 \times 2$ determinants of the two $2 \times 2$ submatrices (first two rows and columns, last two rows and columns), and multiply them.

Comment: Ah I see.  So we don't even have to worry about the 

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
?

Comment: Yup. Look up "determinant of block matrix" for references.

Comment: So would the determinant be the same if the matrix was this?
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
          0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Comment: I have posted a solution to the same problem a few days ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239762/diagonalization-help-me-to-to-find-out-which-one/2239798#2239798  Also, you should look at the comments following the post.

Comment: Yes. Those four entries are irrelevant and don't affect the determinant.

Comment: At the same time, when you see that much zeros in a matrix, the time to find a clever method, you could have calculated it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Result 1**: Eigenvalues of the matrix in a triangular form is the entries of the principal diagonal. For example, if we have the following matrix (Upper triangular)

\begin{bmatrix}         2 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\         0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\         0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\           0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\         \end{bmatrix}

Then eigenvalues of this matrix are given by the entries of principal diagonal which are $2, 2, ,2 ,2$. That is $2$ with algebraic multiplicity $4$.

Generalized form of above result can be summarized from the below example which may help you to solve your problem.

Consider the following matrix

\begin{bmatrix}         A_1 & B  \\  \mathcal{O} & A_2 \\         \end{bmatrix}

where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are square matrices and $\mathcal{O}$ is the matrix with zero entries.

Eigenvalue of above matrix can be obtained by computing the eigenvalues of matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$. Since Characteristic polynomial of this matrix is the product of Characteristic polynomial of $A_1$ and $A_2$.

In your problem you can take $A_1 $ to be

\begin{bmatrix}        2 & 1  \\  1 & 2 \\         \end{bmatrix}

and

$A_2 $ to be

\begin{bmatrix}        2 & 1  \\  1 & 2 \\         \end{bmatrix}